# Running a Java file from Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jar

I'm writing a simple Java program for my history final project and am having trouble exporting it out of eclipse so it can be run on my teacher's computer (a Mac).

Here is the code:

```
package project;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Denim {

        public static void main(String []args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What item of denim is in question?");
            String str = scan.nextLine();
            String str1 = str.toUpperCase();
            String jeans = "JEANS";
            String jeansp = "JEAN PANTS";
            String tux = "CANADIAN TUXEDO";
            String tux1 = "CANADIEN TUXEDO";
            String tux2 = "CANADIAN TUX";
            String tux3 = "CANADIEN TUX";
            String jacket = "JACKET";
            String jjacket = "JEAN JACKET";
            String hat = "HAT";
            String dhat = "DENIM BASEBALL HAT";
            String bhat = "BASEBALL HAT";
            String c = "C";
            int jeanFactor = 9982;
            double jacketFactor = 10466.25178;
            double bottleFactor = 128/16.9;
            double hatFactor = 314.1415;
            if (str1.equals(jeans) || str1.equals(jeansp)){
                System.out.println("How many pairs of jeans?");
                int numj = scan.nextInt();
                int gallonj = numj*jeanFactor;
                System.out.println("Producing " + numj + " pairs of jeans would use: ");
                System.out.println(gallonj + " gallons of water");
                double bottlesj = gallonj*bottleFactor;
                System.out.println(bottlesj + " bottles of water");}
            else if ((str1.equals(tux)) || (str1.equals(tux1)) || (str1.equals(tux2)) ||(str.equals(tux3))){
                System.out.println("How many tuxedos?");
                int numt = scan.nextInt();
                int gallontp = numt * jeanFactor;
                double gallontj = numt * jacketFactor;
                double gallont = gallontp + gallontj;
                double bottlest = gallont*bottleFactor;
                System.out.println("Producing " + numt +" " + c + str.substring(1,8) + " tuexedos would use: ");
                System.out.println(gallont +"  gallons of water.");
                System.out.println(bottlest + " bottles of water");}
            else if (str1.equals(jacket) || str.equals(jjacket)){
                System.out.println("How many jackets?");
                int numjj = scan.nextInt();
                double gallonjj = numjj*jacketFactor;
                double bottlesjj = numjj*bottleFactor;
                System.out.println("Producing " + numjj + " jackets would use: ");
                System.out.println(gallonjj + " gallons of water");
                System.out.println(bottlesjj + " bottles of water");}
            else if (str1.equals(hat) || str.equals(dhat) || str.equals(bhat)){
                System.out.println("How many hats?");
                int numh = scan.nextInt();
                double gallonh = numh*hatFactor;
                double bottlesh = numh*bottleFactor;
                System.out.println("Producing " + numh + " jackets would use: ");
                System.out.println(gallonh + " gallons of water");
                System.out.println(bottlesh + " bottles of water");
            }
        }
    }
```

I click file-export and export it as a .jar file, but every time I try and open it to run it, a message pops up saying "The Java JAR file could not be launched. Does anyone know how to fix this or what I'm doing wrong? Both my computer and my teacher's are Macbooks.

Comment: Are you exporting as runnable jar?

Comment: Google on how to export a runnable jar. Then you run it as java -jar thejarfile.jar

Comment: Could you save the `jar` file to your Desktop, then launch it through `Terminal.app` by issuing the following, assuming `myFile.jar` is the name of the file: `$ java -jar ~/Desktop/myFile.jar` ?

Comment: I clicked exported as runnable JAR. I think that it might be an issue with my computer rather than the file. The program runs smoothly in eclipse but will not open.

Comment: I tried typing java -jar thejarfile.jar into terminal, with my file name, but it said "unable to access"